# JSP: Select and pass bean in <form:select...>

Tags: forms, jsp, spring-mvc, javabeans

I have an `ArrayList` of `Offers` I wan't the user to select from a list. Somehow it looks like I'm having problems with the mapping.

Even though the `select` element looks fine and will display all names of my offers, I can't pass the selected Offer to my Controller.

The Controller that receives the Offer:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/setcostumer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String setCostumer(ModelMap map,
            @ModelAttribute("offer") Offer offer) {

        // ...
    }
```

These are the jsps containing the forms, I tried two ways to pass a bean:

jsp one:

```
    <form:form modelAttribute="offer" action="setcostumer" method="post">
        <form:select path="offer">
            <form:options items="${offers}" itemValue="offer"
                itemLabel="offer" />
        </form:select>
```

Reuslt:

> org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 
>       'offer' of bean class [com.me.model.offer]: Bean property 'offer' is not readable
>    or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

jsp two:

```
    <form:form modelAttribute="offer" action="setcostumer" method="post">
        <legend>Choose offer.</legend>
    <form:select path="name" items="${offers}" itemLabel="name" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="continue" />
    </form:form>
```

POST Header: 
name:com.me.model.Offer@27a464d7

Comment: Show us your Offer Class

Comment: there is nothing special in my offer class, it just has two strings , "name" and "description". The problem is, that I have to specify the attribute, which is the name in this case. Spring will then set the name of an offer, which is a bean and not the attribute. If I set no path, there will be an 5xx error. I now save the id of the offer instead of the bean, it's not great but it does the job.